Elastic search: Pattern capture filter get wrong result
I'm using Elastic Search for search message.
I'm using pattern capture to emit token when document have "_".
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "custom_analyzer": {
        "lowercase": true,
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "limit_length_10000",
          "underscore_filter"
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "limit_length_10000": {
        "type": "length",
        "min": 0,
        "max": 10000
      },
      "underscore_filter": {
        "type": "pattern_capture",
        "patterns": [
          "([^_]+)"
        ],
        "preserve_original": false
      }
    }
  }
}

When using match_phrase_prefix query with the search term also containing "_", for example "success_after", it's also tokenized into 2 tokens "success" and "after". The problem is Elastic return all documents in which contain only "success" or "after".
I only want documents that have both tokens in the same order. Can anyone help me to solve this case? Thanks a lot!

Let's explain your problem
Original mapping
PUT /underscored_phrase_original
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "custom_analyzer": {
                    "lowercase": true,
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "limit_length_10000",
                        "underscore_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "limit_length_10000": {
                    "type": "length",
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 10000
                },
                "underscore_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "patterns": [
                        "([^_]+)"
                    ],
                    "preserve_original": false
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}

Query to investigate the original analyzer
POST /underscored_phrase_original/_analyze
{
    "analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
    "text": "success_after"
}

Response
{
    "tokens" : [
        {
            "token" : "success",
            "start_offset" : 0,
            "end_offset" : 13,
            "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position" : 0
        },
        {
            "token" : "after",
            "start_offset" : 0,
            "end_offset" : 13,
            "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position" : 0
        }
    ]
}

Both tokens have the same position. They can't be found by match_phrase_prefix
Modified mapping by the simple_pattern_split analyzer
PUT /underscored_phrase
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "custom_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "text_split_into_tokens_tokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "limit_length_10000"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "text_split_into_tokens_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "simple_pattern_split",
                    "pattern": "_"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "limit_length_10000": {
                    "type": "length",
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 10000
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}

Sample documents
PUT /underscored_phrase/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"text":"success_after"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"text":"success"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"text":"after"}

match_phrase_prefix query
GET /underscored_phrase/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "text": {
                "query": "success after",
                "analyzer": "whitespace"
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "underscored_phrase",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.78038335,
                "_source" : {
                    "text" : "success_after"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


Thanks u for the answer, i also solve this by using character filter
